# Is `sscanf` guaranteed not to change arguments that it doesn't find?

Tags: c, scanf

I have a case where I'm not sure if I'll get enough input for `sscanf`. Can I safely assume that `sscanf` won't mess with any argument that it doesn't find?

For example, in this program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
    sscanf("1 2", "%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c);
    printf("%d %d %d\n", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

> 1 2 0

So, it read two of the three numbers, and didn't mess with the last one. Can I safely assume that all compilers and standard libraries will also leave the last argument alone in this case, or do I need to do something like this:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int a = 0, b = 0, c = 0;
    if (sscanf("1 2", "%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c) != 3) {
        c = 0;
    }
    printf("%d %d %d\n", a, b, c);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What is `read` in the `printf()` in the first fragment?  Did you consider checking the return value from `sscanf()` — it would be 2, but it tells you how many conversion specifications (other than any `%n` conversion specifications) it was able to assign to.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Sorry, I originally had a variable keeping track of the number of characters read, but removed it (and apparently missed it in the first printf).

Comment: That's roughly what I guessed (but it was better to ask and be sure than to make the change and be wrong).  Interestingly, even without the variable defined, it might have compiled if you had `#include <unistd.h>` because `read` would then be a function pointer to the system call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are completely safe.

In C11, 7.21.6.7 The sscanf function

> 2. ...Reaching the end of the string is equivalent to encountering end-of-ﬁle for
> the fscanf function.

7.21.6.2 The fscanf function says,

> 4. The fscanf function executes each directive of the format in turn. When all
> directives have been executed, or if a directive fails (as detailed below), the
> function returns. **Failures are described as input failures (due to the occurrence of an
> encoding error  or the unavailability of input characters)**, or matching failures
> (due to inappropriate input).
>
> 16. The fscanf function returns the value of the macro EOF if an input failure occurs
> before the ﬁrst conversion (if any) has completed.Otherwise, the function returns the
> number of input items assigned.

Your case is an input failure.

Answer (score 4):

From http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/scanf.html:

> ... If the format is exhausted while arguments remain, the excess
>   arguments shall be evaluated but otherwise ignored.

**Edit:** As Kerrek correctly noticed, the above statement does not apply here.
It is about `sscanf("1", "%d", &a, &b, &c)`, and not about 
`sscanf("1", "%d %d %d", &a, &b, &c)` as in the question.

Comment: Does this actually apply? I thought the statement you quoted applies to something like `scanf("%d", &a, &b, &c)`...

Comment: @KerrekSB: You are right, I misunderstood the question. - Will delete answer ... :-(

Comment: Feel free to leave it up, I suppose it's another useful aspect of the function...

Answer (score 3):

The only reference I can find in C11 is for `fscanf`, 7.21.6.2/10, which says:

> the result of the conversion is placed in the object pointed to by the first argument following the format argument that has not already received a conversion result.

I interpret "is placed in" as "is assigned to", and I'd say with reasonable confidence that this means that an assignment happens if and only if there's a match, otherwise the recipient variable isn't touched.

Note that all of the variable argument are *evaluated* before the function call, of course; this has nothing to do with `scanf`.

Answer (score 3):

7.21.6.2, para 21:

```
EXAMPLE 4 In:

    #include <stdio.h>
    /* ... */
    int d1, d2, n1, n2, i;
    i = sscanf("123", "%d%n%n%d", &d1, &n1, &n2, &d2);

the value 123 is assigned to d1 and the value 3 to n1. Because %n can never get 
an input failure, the value of 3 is also assigned to n2. The value of d2 is not 
affected. The value 1 is assigned to i.
```

That's the closest thing that I can find to an assurance that a parameter will not be modified if no corresponding input is available.

Comment: Technically, that's not 'normative', but it is still a strong indication.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I'm actually a little surprised there *isn't* something more normative than that, but I've gone over that section several times, and that's the closest thing I've found that says anything one way or the other. Which means I wouldn't count on it, myself.

Comment: I think §7.21.6.2 ¶4, quoted by [Pepperboy](http://stackoverflow.com/users/907093/pepperboy) in his [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18859803/15168) is the most relevant part.  When there's no more input, the function returns.

Answer (score 1):

Guranteed. [sscanf()](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/tpfhelp/current/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.ztpf-ztpfdf.doc_put.cur/gtpc2/cpp_fscanf-scanf-sscanf.html)  will not assign any  thing to the extra parameters. You can avoid checking for the return value for this

The C library function int `sscanf(const char *str, const char *format, ...)` reads formatted input from a string instead of `stdin`

On success, the function returns the number of items in the argument list successfully filled.

On failure, This `count can match the expected number of items or be less (even zero) in the case of a matching failure.`
In the case of an input failure before any data could be successfully interpreted, EOF is returned.

If there are too many arguments for the conversion specifications, the extra arguments are evaluated but otherwise ignored.

The results are not defined if there are not enough arguments for the conversion specifications.

All three functions `(fscanf, scanf, and sscanf) return` the number of input items that were successfully matched and assigned. The return value does not include conversions that were performed but not assigned (for example, suppressed assignments).

If you check with the Number of Items count That might become false in some cases.