# Does sscanf touch pointers if no match has been found?

Tags: c, scanf

If a line does not match a [fsv]scanf format, does scanf guarantee not to touch the provided pointers that are not matched?

For example, if

```
int int1 = 3;
int int2 = 5;
sscanf(line, "%d %d", &int1, &int2);
```

returns 0, are the integers guaranteed to be still 3 and 5, or can int1 have been changed?

Comment: (Duplicate found by Blue Moon, below)

Answer (score 6):

The short answer is **yes, in your case you can guarantee that `int1` and `int2` have not changed**.

However, I would advise against relying on this behaviour, as it's likely to produce code that is difficult to read -  and because:

---

The long answer is **it depends on your format string**. Looking at the C11 standard for `fscanf` (s7.21.6.2.16), we have:

> The fscanf function returns the value of the macro EOF if an input failure occurs
>   before the first conversion (if any) has completed. Otherwise, the function returns the
>   number of input items assigned, which can be fewer than provided for, or even zero, in
>   the event of an early matching failure.

Critically important is this definition of input items from later in 7.21.6.2:

> An input item is defined as the longest sequence of input characters which does not exceed
>   any specified field width and which is, or is a prefix of, a matching input sequence

So. The number returned by scanf is the number of items read from the stream, not the number of pointers written to.

Additionally relevant is 7.21.6.2.2:

> If the format is exhausted while arguments remain, the excess
>   arguments are evaluated (as always) but are otherwise ignored.

The behaviour of ignoring arguments that aren't written to is also made explicit in an example at the end of that section:

> In:
>
> ```
>     #include <stdio.h>
>     /* ... */
>     int d1, d2, n1, n2, i;
>     i = sscanf("123", "%d%n%n%d", &d1, &n1, &n2, &d2);
> ```
>
> the value `123` is assigned to `d1` and the value `3` to `n1`. Because `%n` can never get an input failure the value of `3` is also assigned to `n2`. The value of `d2` is not affected. The value `1` is assigned to `i`.

In case you're not familiar with `%n`, it's "the number of characters read from the stream so far".

This is a great example to illustrate your question - here we have three pointers written to, and one pointer untouched. But, `fscanf` only returns 1 here - because it only assigned one "input item" from the stream.

So, in your example, yes, if you've got `%d %d` and you pass it something which causes 0 reads, then yes, the pointers will be untouched.

But, if you've got a `%n` in there, then your function could still return 0 or EOF while still consuming some input and writing to pointers. For example:

```
sscanf("aaa","aaa%n%d",&n1,&n2);
```

This writes `3` to `n1`, leaves `n2` untouched, and returns `EOF`. And:

```
sscanf("aaa bbb","aaa%n%d",&n1,&n2);
```

This writes `3` to `n1`, leaves `n2` untouched, and returns 0.

Comment: It's not clear what happens in case of matching failure. The quoted para only guarantees about the items scanned successfully and doesn't say anything unscanned items (pointers). Put it this way: *If* "*scanf" functions zero initialize all the pointers (values) before actual scanning, does it violate anything in the standard?

Comment: @BlueMoon puts in words what was in my mind when asking the question. Does the documentation or spec say anything about this?

Comment: I've edited the answer to more clearly articulate what the standard says. And to change the content from my earlier, incorrect, answer :)

Comment: I found a dup: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858870/is-sscanf-guaranteed-not-to-change-arguments-that-it-doesnt-find](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18858870/is-sscanf-guaranteed-not-to-change-arguments-that-it-doesnt-find) which has something to the extent that fscanf() returns on first failure, which is more relevant.

Comment: Great find. I've voted to close this one.

Comment: Having said that, the accepted answer on that one is about when scanf returns, not whether it will change the arguments (as in your example of "would it be acceptable for scanf to zero all values before scanning")

Comment: It says that the function scans one-by-one *and* returns immediately on first failure, which, still not 100% explicit, is the closest thing that describes the behaviour in question.

Answer (score 0):

There should be at least as many of these arguments as the number of values stored by the format specifier of sscanf. Additional arguments are ignored by the function sscanf.
If line contains say "10 20", then int1 and int2 will be changed to 10 and 20 respectively.
However, if line contains say "aa bb", then int1 and int2 will be retained as 3 and 5 respectively.